# Tests failed on ForeignKey constraints

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a custom "upload from csv" function in my Django application, using a custom `model.Manager` method that receives the result of applying `csv.DictReader` on the csv data. My tests on normal models are okay, but they are failing on models with ForeignKey constraints.

The relevant source codes are as follows

`models.py`

```
class PledgeManager(models.Manager):
    """Custom manager for model Pledge."""

    def from_upload(self, data):
        """Process data from Pledge upload."""
        for obj in data:
            try:
                # get the prospect & fund by natural key
                obj['prospect'] = Prospect.objects.get_by_natural_key(
                    obj['prospect'])
                obj['pledge_fund'] = Fund.objects.get_by_natural_key(
                    obj['pledge_fund'])
                obj['pledge_date'] = datetime.strptime(
                    obj['pledge_date'], r'%d/%m/%Y')
                try:
                    with transaction.atomic():
                        self.create(**obj)
                    ccall_log.debug('Created Pledge object: %s', obj)
                except IntegrityError:
                    ccall_log.error('Cannot create Pledge object: %s', obj)
            except Prospect.DoesNotExist:
                # no prospect
                ccall_log.error(
                    'Cannot create Pledge object, no Prospect: %s', obj)
            except Fund.DoesNotExist:
                # no fund
                ccall_log.error(
                    'Cannot create Pledge object, no Fund: %s', obj)
            except BaseException as exc_:
                ccall_log.exception(exc_)
                ccall_log.error(
                    'Exception encountered during processing: %s', obj)

class Pledge(models.Model):
    """Model for a Pledge."""
    objects = PledgeManager()

    pledge_amount = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Pledge amount', decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=12, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    pledge_fund = models.ForeignKey(Fund, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pledge_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Pledge date')
    prospect = models.ForeignKey(Prospect, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`test_models.py`

```
class TestPledge(TestCase):
    """Test cases for Pledge."""

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        prospect_obj = {
            'ic': 'Test Prospect',
            ...
        }
        Prospect.objects.create(**prospect_obj)
        Fund.objects.create(name='Test Fund')
        cls.pledge_obj_add_1 = {
            'prospect': 'Test Prospect',
            'pledge_amount': '50',
            'pledge_fund': 'Test Fund',
            'pledge_date': '01/03/2017'
        }
        cls.pledge_obj_add_2 = {
            'prospect': 'Test Prospect',
            'pledge_amount': '100',
            'pledge_fund': 'Test Fund',
            'pledge_date': '01/03/2016'
        }

    def test_from_upload_add_pledge(self):
        """Test adding Pledge via custom manager's from_upload()."""
        Pledge.objects.from_upload([self.pledge_obj_add_1])
        self.assertEqual(Pledge.objects.count(), 1)

    def test_from_upload_multiple_pledge(self):
        """Test adding multiple Pledges via custom manager."""
        Pledge.objects.from_upload(
            [self.pledge_obj_add_1, self.pledge_obj_add_2])
        self.assertEqual(Pledge.objects.count(), 2)
```

The first test passed, but the second one failed. Here's the test output:

```
FAIL: test_from_upload_multiple_pledge (ccall.tests.test_models.TestPledge)
Test adding multiple Pledges via custom manager.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nhanh/phonathon/ccall/tests/test_models.py", line 273, in test_from_upload_multiple_pledge
    self.assertEqual(Pledge.objects.count(), 2)
AssertionError: 1 != 2
```

And the log output:

```
ERROR:ccall Cannot create Pledge object, no Prospect: {'pledge_amount': '50','prospect': <Prospect: Test Prospect>, 'pledge_date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 1, 0, 0), 'pledge_fund': <Fund: Test Fund>}
DEBUG:ccall Created Pledge object: {'pledge_amount': '100', 'prospect': <Prospect: Test Prospect>, 'pledge_date': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 1, 0, 0),'pledge_fund': <Fund: Test Fund>}
```

What I don't understand is that the first object throws an error while the second turns out fine (they have the exact same ForeignKey fields). I created a test to add a single Pledge object, it does not throw an error. Did I happen to trigger any nuance of the Django ORM? Thanks for the help!

UPDATED: I have included the implementation of the two relevant models below.

```
class ProspectManager(models.Manager):
    """Custom manager for model Prospect."""

    def get_by_natural_key(self, ic):
        return self.get(ic=ic)

    def from_upload(self, data):
        """Process data from Prospect upload."""
        ...

class Prospect(models.Model):
    """Model for a Prospect."""
    objects = ProspectManager()

    ic = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='IC', unique=True)
    ...

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.ic

class FundManager(models.Manager):
    """Custom manager for model Fund."""

    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get(name=name)

    def from_upload(self, data):
        """Process data from Fund upload."""
        ...


class Fund(models.Model):
    """Model for a Pledge Fund."""
    objects = FundManager()

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Fund name',
                            max_length=50, unique=True)

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: It seems like somehow the Prospect and Fund objects do not exist untill after you have attempted creating the first object. To test this, create another Fund and Pledge, then add two more cls.pledge_obj_add_* JSON objects that use the second Fund an Prospect. You would expect the 3rd object to fail but 4th to pass.

Comment: @Splatmistro amazingly though both objects passed the test. The log output from the first error actually shows that there's a Prospect and a Fund object (`'prospect': <Prospect: Test Prospect>` and `'pledge_fund': <Fund: Test Fund>`) which is why I don't understand how it fails.

Comment: @Splatmistro one more thing to add, I did try out the functionality on the actual dev server and it works without errors _but the test fails_

Comment: Just looking at your code, it looks like it should. _(But then django can hide bugs nicely)_ Maybe your test input data is bad? Run a dump data with the natural key flag and compare the two. (Maybe edit the post with a single object?)

Comment: @Splatmistro The test using one object ran fine. I have updated the original post with it.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Have you tried calling `from_upload` twice and create a single object each time instead of passing both objects in a list?

Comment: Can you include how your natural keys are defined (that bit of the models) and how you're implementation of get_by_natural_key works please?

Comment: @Splatmistro I will add that in the original post!

Comment: @masterfloda I have tried that, but still the first object gave an error and the second passed.

Comment: If you don't find a solution (and I'm dumbstruck, this SHOULD work), you could give [ModelMommy](https://github.com/vandersonmota/model_mommy) a try. That's what I use to test Django models and I love it.

Comment: I'm absolutely stuck too! If you have a repo to this feature available please share it and i'll dig myself. But I'm sure there are similar things (that either do your job or can be changed a small bit).

Comment: @Splatmistro it's at github.com/nguyenhuyanhh/phonathon. Failing tests, so if you want to look at the above example you would need to switch to the 'dev' branch. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @Splatmistro @masterfloda when I developed `from_upload()` for another model, I ran into the same problem. I changed the test to use `setUp()` instead of `setUpTestData()` and the tests all passed. So I guess this is a solution. Slower tests though, considering that `setUpTestData()` only runs once per test class.

Comment: Make sure to delete the entries in `tearDown()` as that will massively ruin your tests.